# copying a word template file and saving it to various file names based upon an exported list

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, ms-word

For work, our client requests we generate a word document incorporating a GIS Image of various locations within a gird, the address, and supporting map information. We're also requested to pull spec sheets of each referenced location. Since multiple locations can show on the gird, it can create an asymmetric ratio of documents to images

Typically the current process involves copying a working word document, changing the required information, saving and then doing the same thing until we're done.

In an effort to try and streamline this process, my current approach involves running a batch command to list the image files within the folder directory

```
DIR /s *.JPG > ImageList.xls
```

and then run a macro with excel to remove the header, trailer and unneeded metadata

```
Sub ImageList()
Set WS_Input = Worksheets("ImageList")

For i = 5 To 1 Step -1
Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next
'Removes Header Information
'CODE WORKS


Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Last5 = Last - 5
For i = Last To Last5 Step -1
Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next
'Removes trailer information
'CODE WORKS

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
A_length = Len(Range("A" & i))
'Determining the total string length including the leading 39 unneeded characters
A_length39 = A_length - 39
'Determining the total string length removing the leading 39 unneeded characters
Range("A" & i).Copy
WS_Input.Range("A" & i).Value = Right(WS_Input.Range("A" & i), A_length39)
'Removes the unneeded leading characters and repastes them
 Next

End Sub
```

This is where I get stuck; am I better running a batch command (for which I'm not sure how to have the command prompt loop through providing a different name for each iteration, as most example appear to append a suffix or prefix to an already existing file) or write an additional macro within word (which again, I'm not sure how to have vba word reference the cleaned up excel list).

I'm the only one in my group actually trying to implement such methodologies so although I have the support of my bosses, they don't know how to assist.

Comment: Why are you using `DIR /s *.JPG > ImageList.xls`? which will include lots of non required content! Why not open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information for the `DIR` command? You should see that it will allow you to get 'bare` output too! e.g. `Dir /B /S /A:-D *.jpg 2>NUL 1>"ImageList.txt"`.

Comment: That helps clean up the code a little bit (thanks), helping to reduce a couple FOR loops to a find and replace command (to remove the leading directory hierarchy. Still hung up on the referencing though

Comment: Why not use the build in `Dir` function from VBA, or a fileSystemObject?

Comment: Redirecting the `dir` command will certainly not create a valid Excel but a text file…

Comment: On reddit, I ended getting the reccomendation of using the file copy command using concatation